# Would using "ergo" be appropriate in social sciences-related academic writing?

Tags: latin, academia

An example would be

> Yet, this process is by definition neutral, *ergo* affecting all factors in the same way.

I would like to use it sometimes, as an alternative to therefore, so, in consequence, etc. But the truth is I have never seen it in academic papers in my field.

PS: if used, I guess it has to be in italics.

Update: I was thinking on ergo as the latin word (no idea it existed in English). It is common to use other latin expressions like *ad-hoc*, *ex-post*, *ceteris paribus*, etc.

Comment: What did your dictionary say?  According to my dictionary, "ergo" is an English adverb meaning "therefore".  If you do not want to write "therefore" (why not?) you can write "ergo".  No need for italics.

Comment: I don't think you can get away with it in economics. But perhaps psychology will allow it?

Comment: No idea it was an actual English word! Thanks for that. I'm surprised I have never seen it used. Not that I'm a a great reader, but still. Why would economics be different? That is my field.

Comment: @luchonacho Economics is my field too, and I have _never_ seen it used there. I don't know about psychology, but I think they are weird in many ways, so why not in this way?

Comment: It sounds like a terrible affectation outside anything less uptight that a formal mathematical proof. But this is a completely opinion-based question that has no possible "right" answer.

Comment: @luchonacho - Following your remark, I checked if "ergo" is also a French word. and ... it is. What surprised me, because I never read any French text (academic or other) using it; except in the famous Descartes quote "cogito, ergo sum".

Comment: @Graffito You might be (un)surprised to know that it is also a [Spanish word](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G1hfEW8), of which I had no idea. And Spanish is my mother tongue!!! It seems it is time to bring it to the mainstream. Latin languages speakers of the world, unite?

Comment: @tchrist I have never seen it in (English) mathematics either. Perhaps in _ergonomics_?

Comment: I read a lot of academic papers, especially related to medical and social sciences (but not math). I cannot remember ever seeing 'ergo' used. I would not do it.

Comment: Does "ergo" add any meaning that "therefore" or "and so" does not? If not, then "ergo" just comes off as sounding like a pretentious poseur. I would immediately stop reading at "ergo." People who want to impress with their Latin vocabulary should just go ahead and write the whole paper in Latin, and then present it orally in Latin. Now that WOULD be impressive. Otherwise, just sillly "puff words."

Comment: As @curious-proofreader has indicated, *ergo* is a Latin word, which explains why one finds it in the dictionaries of different (western) languages, like other Latin words and phrases, *et cetera*.

Answer (score 2):

*Ergo* appears to be used in the social sciences (although somewhat rarely). I found some papers at random that use "ergo".

Interestingly enough, "ergo" may or may not be italicized when used (as you can see from these examples). I'm not sure why; you may want to ask your advisor what you should do.

[De-Westernizing communication/social science research: opportunities and limitations](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shelton_Gunaratne/publication/249722648_De-Westernizing_communication_science_research_Opportunities_and_limitations/links/5498571d0cf2519f5a1ddff0.pdf):

> These problems applied generally to the plight of social science – and, *ergo*, to media and communication studies as well – in the entire global ‘periphery’.

[The Status of the “Material” in Theories of Culture: From “Social Structure” to “Artefacts”](http://is.muni.cz/el/1423/jaro2015/SOC757/um/3b_Reckwitz.pdf):

> Ergo, the sociology of knowledge is based on the idea of a “double-structure” forming the condition of action: The orderliness of action in social collectivities depends on a shared cultural structure of knowledge.

Comment: Good pick up. However. [as someone who has written in the academic psychology field] I would recommend never using it in academic papers. An excellent publication can be taken out of contention for a top-tier journal and relegated to second-line journals and  field newspapers for such things as simple as appearing pompous.

Comment: Yeaaah, considering how much gets published that really *is* pompous, and the fact that "ergo" is a perfectly valid word, I doubt think there is much risk from using it properly.

Comment: I don't it needs to be italicized. It's an English word as much as it is Latin.